# iO exception while calling WL.Client.pinTrustedCertificatePublicKey MobileFirst

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst, ssl-certificate, cross-platform

i want to apply MobileFirst SSLpinning feature on my hybrid mobile first app , and i replaced the .cer file under certificates folder but while calling :

> WL.Client.pinTrustedCertificatePublicKey(name of certificate)

i am using MobileFirst ver 7.1

i got the following exception :

> W/System.err(32458):  at
>   com.worklight.wlclient.certificatepinning.HostNameVerifierWithCertificatePinning.verify(HostNameVerifierWithCertificatePinning.java:48)
>   W/System.err(32458):  at
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:408)
>   W/System.err(32458):  at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:219)
>   W/System.err(32458):  at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:172)
>   W/System.err(32458):  at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:130)
>   W/System.err(32458):  at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.executeOriginal(DefaultRequestDirector.java:1337)
>   W/System.err(32458):  at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:705)
>   W/System.err(32458):  at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:578)
>   W/System.err(32458):  at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:494)
>   W/System.err(32458):  at
>   com.worklight.wlclient.WLRequestSender.run(WLRequestSender.java:47) 
>   W/System.err(32458):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
>   W/System.err(32458):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
>   W/System.err(32458):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

any help please ?

Comment: The exact exception and the error description seems to be missing at the top of the stack trace, can you paste that please

Comment: Which device does the error occur on?

Comment: i am using android device

Comment: @Srik , the above what i got exactly

Comment: I tried the same and it works fine. Please provide a reproducible sample to verify the issue. You could upload this to dropbox and share the link here.

Comment: @S.A.NortonStanley, can you please share with me the sample you created and working ok with you ?